# Allow line breaks between adjacent elements that can't have line breaks

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML form containing a big group of checkboxes and labels laid out in a row. It's big enough to wrap onto a second physical line. I'm trying to make sure each label stays next to its checkbox (instead of the first line ending with a checkbox that has its label at the start of the next line) by wrapping each pair in a span that forbids line breaks using `white-space: nowrap`.

This works, but causes side effects.

In Chrome, the line is broken in an allowed place, but it's slightly too late. If the first line has room for 7 checkboxes and labels, it puts 8 of them there, overflowing the right border of the parent element, then continues with the 9th pair on the next line.

In IE9, the line doesn't break at all, just ends up as a giant overflow.

http://jsfiddle.net/pmhrx/1/ shows the IE problem, and while creating that, I accidentally discovered a weird workaround: if there is no inter-element whitespace before the `</span>` closing tag, IE adds line breaks correctly! See div2 and div2a in the fiddle - the only difference between them is that extra whitespace, and IE renders them quite differently.

What is going on here and how do I fix it properly? (Please no hackery like forcing everything to exact pixel widths and manually breaking the lines - the list of checkboxes is dynamic)

Comment: I can’t see the described problem in Chrome in your fiddle … Anyway, I would just put the checkboxes into the labels (eliminates the need for the for attribute as well), leave all the surrounding spans out, and just have the labels have `white-space:no-wrap`.

Comment: I haven't managed to reproduce the Chrome problem in the fiddle. It's less important anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if i understand correctly what you want is to keep all checks and labels together.
For that you may use this property:

```
span {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

The "nowrap" property that you want to use applies only for texts.

See your example here http://jsfiddle.net/pmhrx/3/

Comment: inline-block is exactly the right thing! I couldn't come up with it myself because I was just too certain that the answer to my wrapping problem had to have the word "wrap" in it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the cases where simply using `<table>`'s and `text-align:left;` or `right;` will prove to solve this more easily than pixel-hacks, unless I'm misunderstanding your goal.

Comment: How is table hackery any better? How do I know how many table cells I can fit in a line, and keep that information accurate as the dynamically generated list of checkboxes changes?

Comment: There is nothing inherently hacky about tables, and it's better (as far as my understanding of your issue goes), because you can use `text-align:left / right;` to position elements on the fly, as well as set column/cell min,max, or set widths.